# Scilab convert cell from matrix to string

Tags: string, file, matrix, scilab

Hello, I am beginner in Scilab and I have for homework process the measured values, which are saved in csv file. This is example of the values in that file:

```
&quot;Project Name:,&lt;Empty&gt;&quot;<br />
&quot;Company Name:,&lt;Empty&gt;&quot;<br />
&quot;User Name:,&lt;Empty&gt;&quot;<br />
&quot;Job Title:,&lt;Empty&gt;&quot;<br />
&quot;Location:,&lt;Empty&gt;&quot;<br />
&quot;Remarks:,&lt;Empty&gt;&quot;<br />
&quot;Date_Time,Test ID,Value_A,Unit_A,Function_A,MeterID_A,BluetoothID_A,Remarks_A&quot;<br />
&quot;2021-03-11 16:59:54,TP0,1968.2,Ω,Res,U1252B-MY52430232,U1177A-238EBF,&quot;<br />
&quot;2021-03-11 16:59:55,TP1,1967.6,Ω,Res,U1252B-MY52430232,U1177A-238EBF,&quot;<br />
&quot;2021-03-11 16:59:56,TP2,1966.9,Ω,Res,U1252B-MY52430232,U1177A-238EBF,&quot; &quot;2021-03-11 16:59:57,TP3,1966.5,Ω,Res,U1252B-MY52430232,U1177A-238EBF,&quot; &quot;2021-03-11 16:59:58,TP4,1966,Ω,Res,U1252B-MY52430232,U1177A-238EBF,&quot; &quot;2021-03-11 16:59:59,TP5,1964,Ω,Res,U1252B-MY52430232,U1177A-238EBF,&quot; &quot;2021-03-11 17:00:00,TP6,1945.5,Ω,Res,U1252B-MY52430232,U1177A-238EBF,&quot; &quot;2021-03-11 17:00:01,TP7,1895.1,Ω,Res,U1252B-MY52430232,U1177A-238EBF,&quot; &quot;2021-03-11 17:00:02,TP8,1856.6,Ω,Res,U1252B-MY52430232,U1177A-238EBF,&quot; &quot;2021-03-11 17:00:03,TP9,1824.7,Ω,Res,U1252B-MY52430232,U1177A-238EBF,&quot; &quot;2021-03-11 17:00:04,TP10,1803,Ω,Res,U1252B-MY52430232,U1177A-238EBF,&quot; &quot;2021-03-11 17:00:05,TP11,1788.7,Ω,Res,U1252B-MY52430232,U1177A-238EBF,&quot; &quot;2021-03-11 17:00:06,TP12,1773.5,Ω,Res,U1252B-MY52430232,U1177A-238EBF,&quot; &quot;2021-03-11 17:00:07,TP13,1759.8,Ω,Res,U1252B-MY52430232,U1177A-238EBF,&quot; &quot;2021-03-11 17:00:08,TP14,1752.9,Ω,Res,U1252B-MY52430232,U1177A-238EBF,&quot; &quot;2021-03-11 17:00:09,TP15,1744.3,Ω,Res,U1252B-MY52430232,U1177A-238EBF,&quot; &quot;2021-03-11 17:00:10,TP16,1734.4,Ω,Res,U1252B-MY52430232,U1177A-238EBF,&quot; &quot;2021-03-11 17:00:11,TP17,1727.9,Ω,Res,U1252B-MY52430232,U1177A-238EBF,&quot; &quot;2021-03-11 17:00:12,TP18,1723.8,Ω,Res,U1252B-MY52430232,U1177A-238EBF,&quot; &quot;2021-03-11 17:00:13,TP19,1718.5,Ω,Res,U1252B-MY52430232,U1177A-238EBF,&quot; &quot;2021-03-11 17:00:14,TP20,1713.5,Ω,Res,U1252B-MY52430232,U1177A-238EBF,&quot; &quot;2021-03-11 17:00:15,TP21,1710.3,Ω,Res,U1252B-MY52430232,U1177A-238EBF,&quot; &quot;2021-03-11 17:00:16,TP22,1708.4,Ω,Res,U1252B-MY52430232,U1177A-238EBF,&quot; &quot;2021-03-11 17:00:17,TP23,1706.4,Ω,Res,U1252B-MY52430232,U1177A-238EBF,&quot; &nbsp;
```

I am trying to get only the value of resistances with these commands:

```
 dates = mgetl(&#39;NTC2k2.csv&#39;) 
[start, final, match] = regexp(dates(1:$,1)),&#39;/[1-9.]*,Ω/&#39;)
```

But my BIG problem is that when I try use this code it throw exeption that the function regexp cannot work with matrix dates(1:$,1), please I do not know how to proceed next. Please help me, thanks you very much!

Comment: Could you please give access to you *original* file ? I think that the html like you posted has been corrupted when copy/pasting ?

Comment: of course, sorry I noted about this comment now. there I am putting the whole file :-)
http://leteckaposta.cz/268429193

Comment: There will be no problem to read this file with `csvRead, just precise that the separator is a semicolon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that you had some problems when pasting you csv file. If the file has the following content, which I suppose to be the case since a CSV file is not supposed to include html entities:

```
Project Name:,<Empty>
Company Name:,<Empty>
User Name:,<Empty>
Job Title:,<Empty>
Location:,<Empty>
Remarks:,<Empty>
Date_Time,Test ID,Value_A,Unit_A,Function_A,MeterID_A,BluetoothID_A,Remarks_A
2021-03-11 16:59:54,TP0,1968.2,Ω,Res,U1252B-MY52430232,U1177A-238EBF
2021-03-11 16:59:55,TP1,1967.6,Ω,Res,U1252B-MY52430232,U1177A-238EBF
2021-03-11 16:59:56,TP2,1966.9,Ω,Res,U1252B-MY52430232,U1177A-238EBF
2021-03-11 16:59:57,TP3,1966.5,Ω,Res,U1252B-MY52430232,U1177A-238EBF
2021-03-11 16:59:58,TP4,1966,Ω,Res,U1252B-MY52430232,U1177A-238EBF
2021-03-11 16:59:59,TP5,1964,Ω,Res,U1252B-MY52430232,U1177A-238EBF
2021-03-11 17:00:00,TP6,1945.5,Ω,Res,U1252B-MY52430232,U1177A-238EBF
2021-03-11 17:00:01,TP7,1895.1,Ω,Res,U1252B-MY52430232,U1177A-238EBF
2021-03-11 17:00:02,TP8,1856.6,Ω,Res,U1252B-MY52430232,U1177A-238EBF
2021-03-11 17:00:03,TP9,1824.7,Ω,Res,U1252B-MY52430232,U1177A-238EBF
2021-03-11 17:00:04,TP10,1803,Ω,Res,U1252B-MY52430232,U1177A-238EBF
2021-03-11 17:00:05,TP11,1788.7,Ω,Res,U1252B-MY52430232,U1177A-238EBF
2021-03-11 17:00:06,TP12,1773.5,Ω,Res,U1252B-MY52430232,U1177A-238EBF
2021-03-11 17:00:07,TP13,1759.8,Ω,Res,U1252B-MY52430232,U1177A-238EBF
2021-03-11 17:00:08,TP14,1752.9,Ω,Res,U1252B-MY52430232,U1177A-238EBF
2021-03-11 17:00:09,TP15,1744.3,Ω,Res,U1252B-MY52430232,U1177A-238EBF
2021-03-11 17:00:10,TP16,1734.4,Ω,Res,U1252B-MY52430232,U1177A-238EBF
2021-03-11 17:00:11,TP17,1727.9,Ω,Res,U1252B-MY52430232,U1177A-238EBF
2021-03-11 17:00:12,TP18,1723.8,Ω,Res,U1252B-MY52430232,U1177A-238EBF
2021-03-11 17:00:13,TP19,1718.5,Ω,Res,U1252B-MY52430232,U1177A-238EBF
2021-03-11 17:00:14,TP20,1713.5,Ω,Res,U1252B-MY52430232,U1177A-238EBF
2021-03-11 17:00:15,TP21,1710.3,Ω,Res,U1252B-MY52430232,U1177A-238EBF
2021-03-11 17:00:16,TP22,1708.4,Ω,Res,U1252B-MY52430232,U1177A-238EBF
2021-03-11 17:00:17,TP23,1706.4,Ω,Res,U1252B-MY52430232,U1177A-238EBF
```

then the Scilab code to get the resistance column is very simple (I suppose that your file is named `so.csv`)

```
--> csvRead("so.csv",[],[],"double",[],[],[],7)(:,3)

ans  =

   1968.2
   1967.6
   1966.9
   1966.5
   1966.
   1964.
   1945.5
   1895.1
   1856.6
   1824.7
   1803.
   1788.7
   1773.5
   1759.8
   1752.9
   1744.3
   1734.4
   1727.9
   1723.8
   1718.5
   1713.5
   1710.3
   1708.4
   1706.4
```

the last parameter with value `7` indicates the number of lines in the header of the file and the recursive extraction `(:,3)` selects the third column.

Answer (score 0):

The example `CSV` that you posted seems to contain `HTML` entities such as `&quot;` which represents the double-quote character `"`, `&#39;` which represents the single quote character `'`, `&lt;` and `&gt;` which represent the characters `<` and `>`, respectively. If this is an encoding problem in your original data, then you should re-encode the file because data in a `CSV` file should be separated by a delimiter (usually the comma or space character).

Now to the main point, the issue here is that `mgetl()` returns a vector of strings, with each string representing a line in your file.
However, according to Scilab's documentation for [regexp](https://help.scilab.org/doc/5.5.2/en_US/regexp.html), the first argument must be a string. Therefore, you should either concatenate the vector of strings into a single string or you can read the whole file directly into a string and then run your `RegEx`.
Below is a snippet that gets the number of bytes in your data file, then reads the entire file into a string using [mgetstr](https://help.scilab.org/docs/6.1.0/en_US/mgetstr.html), a function that accepts the number of chars to read and a file descriptor obtained through [mopen](https://help.scilab.org/docs/6.1.0/en_US/mopen.html), and then runs a `RegEx` pattern to obtain the resistor values. As a final step, it converts the matched strings vector into a vector of doubles.

```
byte_len = fileinfo('NTC2k2.csv')(1);
str = mgetstr(byte_len, mopen('NTC2k2.csv'));
[_, _, res_vals] = regexp(str,'/((?<=\,)\d+(\.\d+)?(?=\,Ω))+/');
res_vals = strtod(res_vals);
```

**Note**: The pattern uses lookarounds (`(?<=...)` and `(?=...)`) to assert that what immediately precede and follow a resistor value are a `,` and `,Ω`, respectively. The in-between pattern `\d+(\.\d+)?` matches the integral part of the resistor value and, if any, its fractional part.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you very much! :-)
btw if I understand correctly from the command there is no note the separator (which is in this case comma ,) so do I guess the comma is set as the default separator?

Comment: Yes but you can change this if the seperator is different (semicolon or else). This is the second parameter : `csvRead(filename, separator, decimal, conversion, substitute, regexpcomments, range, header)`. See the help page of `csvRead` for more details.